# weblogic in docker trying to use the public port in the container when 7101:7001 port mapping is used

Tags: docker, docker-compose, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am starting a WebLogic 12.2.1.4 admin server in docker from my *docker-compose.yml* file.

**I use different port mapping, not the default 7001.**

My docker port mapping is this: 7101:7001

Everything works fine, except this: I constantly get the following exception when I click on the *Deployment* menu on the web console:

```
<Feb 12, 2021 5:11:21,002 PM UTC> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=All Servers : Resolving connection list DomainRuntimeServiceMBean> 
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'localhost', port: '7101'
failed reasons:
 [0] address:'localhost/127.0.0.1',port:'7101' : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

The WL admin server tries to use the public docker port 7101 in the container but actually, WL is listening on the default 7001 port inside the container. Port 7101 is only used from the host machine, and of course, WL is not listening on port 7101 in the container.

My workaround is the following:

1. Check the IP address of the admin-server container with `docker inspect <container-name>`
2. Open the WL console using the container private IP address, e.g.: http://172.19.0.2:7001/console
3. In this case, the exception does not appear
4. But if I open the WL console from http://localhost:7101/console which is the mapped port to the host machine by docker, then the exception appears

Maybe this is a WL user interface issue? But I am not sure.

Any idea why this happening?

Comment: I am running into this same issue. I am however just deploying an ADF application (EAR file) and when running it I see this issue. If I figure it out I will provide an update.

Comment: I am not sure what was the solution because I have modified multiply things, but I solved that. You can pull and use the working solution from [here](https://github.com/zappee/docker-images). Check the _Admin Server_ and the _Managed Server_ images. I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Did you ever mess with the way that they start up?

Comment: No , I did not.